# MySQL reorder Number values

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with values

```
ID(PK) MAIN_ID  SUB_ID
1         2        2
2         2        3
5         1        1
3         1        3
9         1        4
8         1        5
4         4        2
7         4        3
11        4        4
10        4        6
6         4        7
12        4        8
```

I want to reorder them in such a way that MAIN_ID's will contain 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 and SUB_IDs will container 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 etc. Basically i want to remove the missing numbers and make the MAIN_ID and SUB_ID follow numerical order without missing numbers

Desired result as requested

````
ID(PK)  MAIN_ID           SUB_ID
1         2                1(Prev 2)
2         2                2(Prev 3)
5         1                1
3         1                2(Prev 3)
9         1                3(Prev 4)
8         1                4(Prev 5)
4         3(Prev 4)        1(Prev 2)
7         3(Prev 4)        2(Prev 3)
11        3(Prev 4)        3(Prev 4)
10        3(Prev 4)        4(Prev 6)
6         3(Prev 4)        5(Prev 7)
12        3(Prev 4)        6(Prev 8)
```
````

Comment: Do you mean `order by main_id, sub_id`?

Comment: Sub will depend on the number of values. It can be 1-4, 1-6, 1-7, 1-8 etc depending on how many subtopics sub has. It acts like a subheading to a mainheading. and the subID is used to order the subtopics inside each heading @Strawberry

Comment: Not ordering. I want to change the values so that they don't have missing values. In the case of heading, 3 is missing @juergend

Comment: Please check the eidted question @Strawberry

Comment: The main id in your sample result doesn't contain 1,2,3,4. Your explanation needs some revision.

Comment: I want to edit the table values. The main id values were previously 4 and the result should be 3 and so on @Strawberry

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Comment: And clarify which version of MySQL you're using

Comment: The latest one @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this:

```
UPDATE test
JOIN ( SELECT ID, 
              DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MAIN_ID) dr,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MAIN_ID ORDER BY SUB_ID, ID) rn
       FROM test ) t USING (ID)
SET test.MAIN_ID = dr, test.SUB_ID = rn;
```

?

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6202cde58575b42868d65f46039ef513)